# How to programmatically clear the content of the input field (sendbox) in the chat window | MS Bot framework | Directline bot

Tags: javascript, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm using QnAMaker in the back end for my chat bot, which is running in direct line bot channel. In a situation i want to clear the contents in the input field, for that i've used the following simple JavaScript line

```
document.querySelector("[aria-label='Sendbox']").value ="";
```

It clears the content at that moment, however it appears again when we click inside the input field to type the next question. Hence the content is actually not cleared.

So suggest me a way with which i should programmatically clear the input field (sendbox) of the chat window permanently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in this answer: [How to add AutoComplete/AutoSuggestion in Microsoft botframework webchat using React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223610/how-to-add-autocomplete-autosuggestion-in-microsoft-botframework-webchat-using-r/60271292#60271292)

> Web Chat uses [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) which has a [Redux store](https://redux.js.org/basics/store) that can use
>   [Redux middleware](https://medium.com/@jacobp100/you-arent-using-redux-middleware-enough-94ffe991e6). Web chat has an action called
>   [`WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/core/src/actions/setSendBox.js) that can be used to respond to what the
>   user types in the text input box like this:
>
> ```
> const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
>     {},
>     store => next => action => {
>         if (action.type === 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX') {
>             const user_entered_text = action.payload.text;
>
>             // Use the text to query the Azure database and display suggestions
>         }
>         return next(action);
>     }
> );
> ```
>
> When the user clicks on a suggestion or presses the right key, you can
>   use that same action to change what's in the text input box like this:
>
> ```
> store.dispatch({
>     type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
>     payload: {
>         text: user_selected_suggestion,
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> There are [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/j.redux-actions) in the Web Chat repo that may help with using
>   Redux actions in Web Chat

You're trying to edit the contents of the send box without using the Redux store, and so Web Chat isn't aware of the changes you're trying to make. If you use the `WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX` action with empty text then you can clear the send box correctly.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, i found the solution based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution for the issue is the following piece of code.

```
function clearinput()
{

                    store.dispatch({
                    type: 'WEB_CHAT/SET_SEND_BOX',
                    payload: {

                            text: "",
                         }
                    });
                         document.querySelector("[aria-label='Sendbox']").value ="";


}
```

thanks Kyle Delaney for the detailed explanation, based on your input I've achieved it.

Comment: You don't need the `document.querySelector` part